# Remove classes from post_class()

Tags: filters, post-class

I am trying to tidy up the `post_class` function.

I've managed to remove "hentry" class using the filter below, but I would also like to remove the "post-id", "type-" and "status-" classes as well. How can I use my filter to do this?

```
function lsmwp_remove_postclasses( $classes ) {
    $classes = array_diff( $classes, array( 'hentry' ) );
    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'post_class','lsmwp_remove_postclasses' );
```

Comment: this sounds wrong. what would be a reason for doing such a thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to use `preg_match` and remove classes that matches given patterns, but... Since we know `$post_id`, we can use your code with a tiny modification:

```
function lsmwp_remove_postclasses($classes, $class, $post_id) {
    $classes = array_diff( $classes, array(
        'hentry',
        'post-' . $post_id,
        'type-' . get_post_type($post_id),
        'status-' . get_post_status($post_id),
    ) );
    return $classes;
}
add_filter('post_class', 'lsmwp_remove_postclasses', 10, 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
add_filter( 'post_class', 'remove_hentry_function', 20 );
function remove_hentry_function( $classes ) {
    if( ( $key = array_search( 'hentry', $classes ) ) !== false )
        unset( $classes[$key] );
    return $classes;
}
```

[Here](https://php.quicoto.com/how-to-remove-a-class-from-post_class-wordpress/) is reference

It removing the **"hentry"** class.

Comment: Hmm... I'm pretty sure that `hentry` class is already removed with code posted in question...