# Remove Extra Classes from Post Title

Tags: filters, post-class

I want to remove tag, category classes from Post Titles of my WordPress blog. On the frontend, Wordpress generates extra classes for every single article title.

For Example, [this article](https://examsmate.in/indian-army-preparation-tips/), has these article title classes "category-tips-guides" "tag-indian-army" as displayed in the following image:

[image]

I have tried the following snippet to remove some extra classes ([shared on this page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/302055/remove-classes-from-post-class?rq=1)) and it works:

```
function lsmwp_remove_postclasses($classes, $class, $post_id) {
$classes = array_diff( $classes, array(
    'hentry',
    'type-' . get_post_type($post_id),
    'status-' . get_post_status($post_id),
) );
return $classes;
add_filter('post_class', 'lsmwp_remove_postclasses', 10, 3);
```

But the issue with this code is that it doesn't remove any Tag, Category classes as I want.

**Some References to post_class:**

1. https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class
2. https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.9.7/src/wp-includes/post-template.php#L0

Comment: Is jQuery an option?

Comment: No sir, No jQuery, please. Currently, my blog doesn't make use of jQuery. So, I don't want to use jQuery just for this single purpose. Hope you understand :)

Comment: jQuery is a part of WordPress core. So even if you don't use it, WordPress already uses it anyway. You should be more specific in your question. It would help if you edit your question and add some HTML examples where these classes appear and what exactly you want to remove.

Comment: Actually, I want to remove these classes from the Post Title, generated at the front end where I don't have any jQuery. Question Updated with more specific details. Thanks :)

Comment: Just for info: WordPress also utilizes jQuery in the frontend.

Comment: Yes, it may be utilized by WP on the frontend but my blog doesn't require one so I have disabled the jQuery from loading on my site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
// **** Remove unwanted classes
function remove_classes($classes, $class, $post_id)
{
    // Array that holds the undesired classes
    $removeClasses = array(
        'category-',
        'tag-'
    );

    // Array to store the new class names
    $newClasses = array();
    foreach ($classes as $_class)
    {
        // Iterate through the array of undesired classes and
        // check if the current $_class name starts with the
        // undesired class name
        $hasClass = FALSE;
        foreach ($removeClasses as $_removeClass)
        {
            if (strpos($_class, $_removeClass) === 0)
            {
                $hasClass = TRUE;
                break;
            }
        }

        // If $_class does not contain an undesired class name,
        // add it to the array of new class names.
        if (!$hasClass)
        {
            $newClasses[] = $_class;
        }
    }

    // Return the array of new class names
    return ($newClasses);
}
add_filter('post_class', 'remove_classes', 10, 3);
```

This filter declares an array of undesired class names (`$removeClasses`). Expand it with the class names you don't want to have.

Then, the function iterates through the passed array of classes (`$classes`) and checks if it contains classes you have defined in the `$removeClasses` array. If not, it will add it to a new array (`$newClasses`). If yes, it will skip it.

Finally it returns the new array `$newClasses`.

Basically it sorts out the classes you don't want. And instead of manipulating the passed `$classes` array, it creates a new one with only the good classes and returns that instead.

I haven't tested it though. I don't have a WordPress installation available here right now to fiddle around with. It could be that it doesn't work, because `post_class` might not be the right filter.

Comment: Thanks, Mate but this snippet is causing fatal error resulting in the whole site down.

Comment: @NarenderChopra I just tested the code and it works fine. Please see http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/2qrp-ane1  - Please enable error reporting in your code: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: @NarenderChopra I updated the code. I think it might be caused because I forgot the add the `$priority` and `$accepted_args` parameters to the `add_filter` function. Try `add_filter('post_class', 'remove_classes', 10, 3);` instead.

Comment: Thanks a ton, Mate. It finally worked. The perfect solution for my need :)

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you will also have to remove all elements from `$classes` that begin with `tag-` and `category-`. The difficult is that other than with `type-` and `status-` there may be multiple instance of them.

So, you will have to loop through the array and remove any instances that start with these strings:

```
foreach ($classes as $class) {
  if (substr ($class, 0, 4) === "tag-") $class = '';
  if (substr ($class, 0, 8) === "category-") $class = '';
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Actually, I am looking for a code that I can add to my theme's functions.php to remove these extra classes. I don't want to edit core Wordpress files :)

Comment: This is not jquery but php. You simply add it to the filter you already have.

Comment: I am currently using the following function. May you please let me know where to add the strings provided by you:

` function lsmwp_remove_postclasses($classes, $class, $post_id) {
$classes = array_diff( $classes, array(
    'hentry',
    'type-' . get_post_type($post_id),
    'status-' . get_post_status($post_id),
) );
return $classes;
add_filter('post_class', 'lsmwp_remove_postclasses', 10, 3); `

Comment: Insert it before `return $classes;`

Comment: But if you have no idea what your filter actually does it might help to learn a little bit more about php.

Comment: Added it as you said but no effect. Still, WordPress is adding those classes to Post Title.